# Novel power series

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Has anyone collected such novelties:
$1+5+25+125=156=12\cdot13$;
$1+2+4+8=15=3\cdot5$;
$1+2+4+8+16+32=63=7\cdot9$;
$1+18+324=343=7^3$;
$1+3+9+27+81=121=11^2$?

Comment: What do you think the novelty is?

Comment: Those aren't power series; at least not in the usual sense. Are you asking for a general pattern? For verfication (which seems not needed, though)? *What exactly is your question?*

Comment: You can always claim that any particular equation between numbers is a novelty. Sums of powers like these always have the form $(a^n -1)/(a-1)$ and so may occasionally factor in ways that surprise you.

Comment: Ethan Bolker understands that the ordinary expression for the sum of the term is none too exciting.  Hence, I want to see if "novelties" (unexpected ways of expressing the sums) have been noticed and saved.  Of course, one must have a sense of  mathematical novelty to understand the query.  Items like -1=e to the i*pi would qualify as an unexpected novelty.

Comment: It is still unclear what your question is. Are you asking what is the relationship between your equations and $e^{i \pi} = -1$?

Comment: You suffer from literalism: the expression for -1 is (to me) a novel way to express the quantity and was offered as an example of the unexpected.  See remarks to Bolker.

Comment: math is very literal.

Comment: Recognizing a true novelty is NOT literal.

Comment: novelty is not logic either ...

Comment: The wish to be logical is illogical by definition.  Take 1+7+49+343=400=20*20.  It is illogical to think that this is a lovely novelty iff countless such sums produced squares.

Comment: or products of marked up and down values ... $20\cdot 20=16\cdot 25=10\cdot 40=5\cdot 80=4\cdot 100=2\cdot 200=1\cdot 400$ ...

Comment: How about 1+46+46^2+46^3=palindrome 99499?  Rotate digit 6 in 46 to get digit 9 and place the 4 from 46 in the middle to get 4 nines and 1 four = the 40 from 46.  Can such a true novelty be repeated?

Answer (score 5):

These observations can be summarized with the (well-known) formula
$$
1 + x + \cdots + x^n = \frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x - 1}.
$$
For instance, with $x=3$ and $n=4$ we obtain
$$
1 + 3^1 + \cdots + 3^4 = \frac{3^5 - 1}{3 - 1} = \frac{242}{2} = 121 = 11^2
$$
which confirms your observation.

The fact that such numbers have predictable possibilities for factorization is relevant to what we know about [Mersenne primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).  Mersenne primes are precisely the prime numbers that we can obtain when we take $x = 2$ in the above; notably such a number can only be prime if $n+1$ is prime, but the converse fails to hold.

---

You may find it interesting that whenever $n+1$ is composite (non-prime), the quantity $\frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x-1}$ has a corresponding factorization.  In partiular, we find that if $n+1 = pq$ for integers $p,q > 1$, then
$$
1 + x + \cdots + x^n = \frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x-1} = \frac{(x^{p})^q - 1}{x-1} = \frac {x^p - 1}{x-1} \cdot \frac{(x^p)^q - 1}{x^p - 1} = \\
\frac {x^p - 1}{x-1}\cdot [1 + x^p + \cdots + (x^p)^{q-1}] = \\
[1 + x + \cdots + x^{p-1}] \cdot [1 + x^p + \cdots + (x^p)^{q-1}]
$$

Comment: Ahhhh!  On the right track!  One seeks novelties in the multiplication of these two numbers...are they consecutive or consecutive even numbers or odd numbers?

Comment: If you're looking for products of two numbers that are close to each other, perhaps you should consider the case where $x - 1$ is a perfect square and $n = 2k - 1$ is odd.  In this case, we find that
$$
\frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x-1} = \frac{(x^k - 1)(x^k+1)}{x-1} = \frac{x^k - 1}{\sqrt{x-1}} \cdot \frac{x^k + 1}{\sqrt{x-1}}
$$
this works particularly well for $x = 5$.